# Can Selendroid be used to develop an app? (e.g. instead of WebView)

Tags: android, webview, selendroid

I developed an app using WebView, WebViewClient, WebChromeClient and many other classes... just to automate some aspect of web browsing. The implementation has become so cumbersome that I am thinking perhaps use Selenium instead to automate any browser on the smartphone to accomplish the same thing.

But all references I found suggest that Selendroid is for testing only.

What am I missing in regard to (re)basing my app on Selendroid?

Are there known examples for such apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Blog for Selenium Beginners](http://selenium-breakthrough.blogspot.co.il/2014/04/step-by-step-tutorial-for-running-your.html) suggests that a Selenium test run is invoked from a PC (running Windows, for example) connected via USB. Thus, you can't really expect a user to always be connected to a PC to run your Selendroid-based app.

Bottom line: Selendroid is for testing, not an app development framework. If you need a framework other than the native Android, consider [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/getting-started/android/).